# I need help simplifying some Gamma Functions

Tags: gamma-function

The first equation must be simplified to achieve the result of the second equation, q is just a constant here. I have no clue about which algebraic manipulations I need to use to achieve this result. This solution was obtainned by MAPLE software, however I couldn´t get the steps from this software.

\begin{equation}
\begin{gathered}
\frac{\Gamma(\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{q-1})}{\Gamma(\frac{1}{q-1})}\frac{\Gamma(\frac{q}{q-1})}{ \Gamma(\frac{q}{q-1}+\frac{1}{2})} =
\frac{2}{(q+1)}
\\
\end{gathered}
\end{equation}

Comment: It looks like it's just applying the rule $\Gamma(x+1) = x \Gamma(x)$ on the left.  On the right just cancel terms that appear in numerator and denominator.

Comment: Could you give me the steps ? I couldn´t reach this result.

Comment: Hint: what is $1 + \dfrac{1}{q-1}$?

Comment: Yeah, I know. I already tested multiple approaches and I can´t simplify to reach this result.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you learn how to solve this yourself. Here's a hint:

The LHS simplifies to

$$\frac{\Gamma\left(\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{q-1}\right)\Gamma\left(\frac{1}{q-1}+1\right)}{\Gamma\left(\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{q-1}+1\right)\Gamma\left(\frac{1}{q-1}\right)}$$

... Now you can use $\Gamma(x+1) = x\Gamma(x)$

---

Here are the steps:

We can simplify the expressions above by considering
$$x = \frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{q-1}$$
$$y = \frac{1}{q-1}$$

So that we have the following,

$$\frac{\Gamma(x)\Gamma(y+1)}{\Gamma(x+1)\Gamma(y)}$$

Now using the identity $\Gamma(x+1) = x\Gamma(x)$, we can write out

$$ = \frac{y\Gamma(x)\Gamma(y)}{x\Gamma(x)\Gamma(y)}$$

and now simplifying by cancelling $\Gamma(x)$ and $\Gamma(y)$ we get

$$ = \frac{y}{x}$$
which when plugging expressions for $x$ and $y$ back in yield

$$ = \frac{1}{q-1}\frac{1}{\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{q-1}}$$
$$ = \frac{2(q-1)}{(q-1)(q+1)}$$
$$ = \frac{2}{q+1}$$

Hope that helps!

Comment: shouldn´t the first gamma argument be 1/2+1/q-1 instead of 1/2+q/q-1 ?

Comment: Typo. Did you manage to solve it?

Comment: I can write the steps out if really needed

Comment: I still couldn't achieve this result. I appreciate If you write the steps.